# Access pictures from Pictures app in my android app

Tags: android, android-image

Just like the iPhone has a UIImagePickerController to let the user access pictures stored on the device, do we have a similar control in the Android SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe what you're after is a content provider called android.provider and a class called MediaStore.Images [More information can be found here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use`startActivityForResult`, passing in an Intent that describes an action you want completed and and data source to perform the action on.

Luckily for you, Android includes an Action for picking things: `Intent.ACTION__PICK` and a data source containing pictures: 
`android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for images on the local device or
`android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for images on the SD card.

Call `startActivityForResult` passing in the pick action and the images you want the user to select from like this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Then override `onActivityResult` to listen for the user having made a selection.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
      // TODO Do something with the select image URI
    } 
}
```

Once you have the image Uri you can use it to access the image and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: My onactivityresult not getting called when using this... any suggestion? I set external storage permission

Comment: To see how exactly you retrieve the file path from the selectedImage variable, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10474167

Answer (score 22):

You can also do:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

This will pick images across all storages.

Comment: Is it possible to make the camera show up as an additional source here?

Comment: if you pass the static 1 to the startActivityForResult, how do you identify the request code within the onActivityResult()?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to the answer given by Reto. You could do this to scale the image :

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[]  data = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, uri, data, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```