# What is the best way for pick a video in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore

I got a perfect *Intent.ACTION_PICK* with my picture.

> startActivityForResult(new
>   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
>                                     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
>   SELECT_IMAGE);

But it doesn't work with video. When i click on a video of my list, it play the vidoe instead of send me back.

> startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,                                  android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
>   SELECT_VIDEO);

[image]

An idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and specify `video/*` for the type to pass to `Intent.setType`. See [Stackoverflow - Android access videos and photos on Android 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863313/accessing-videos-and-photos-on-android-1-5) for an example.