# How to get video content into ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I am making an video player app and what i am trying to do is detect all the **video content** from the device and display it in a **ListView**

I don't know how to get that content . Also if there is another way of displaying the video content.
Basically i am trying to build a custom file chooser which displays only video content in a list form.

[image]

what i am trying to achieve is instead of those item1..2..3 i should get video contents from the device

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547130/how-to-get-all-capture-videolist-in-android

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230615/what-is-the-best-way-for-pick-a-video-in-android Or [Other results](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22android.provider.MediaStore.Video%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply but it's not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you tried to do

Comment: Please see the image and last line

Comment: All I see is a preview of your layout from Android Studio. Not actual code

Comment: My first link gives you a `Cursor`, then you can research how to use a `CursorAdapter` to add into a `ListView`