# How to acess images and videos from android SD Card and internal storage

Tags: android

I am launching an intent to access only images and videos to use in my Android application using the below intent as follows.

```
    public static final int IMAGE_PICK = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Any"), IMAGE_PICK);
```

Using the above I am able to see the images in IO File Manager and also gallery, apart from this I am also seeing Contacts API. But here I don't want to display Contacts API.  Any Suggestions.

Thanks&Regards,
Venkat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  public static final int IMAGE_PICK = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Any"), IMAGE_PICK);
```

try this code to open gallery with only images and videos.

Refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863313/accessing-videos-and-photos-on-android-1-5)

Comment: I found that (unsurprisingly) multiple calls to setType with different mime-types only sets the last type (in this case video). What worked for me was one call separating the mime-types with a comma e.g. setType("image/*, video/*");

Comment: This answer doesn't work. The documentation is clear, as @aaronmarino points out, that each call to setType() clears out previous calls.