# Return image to form and display chosen image

Tags: android, image, forms

im making an android application which requires a user to register using a form , the form must take in a username , email and a  users chosen image. The image can be obtained either by using the camera or by browsing a directory. My question is what would be the best way to implement this on a form . For the email and username I am using a the EditText class , I was planning on using a spinner for the choice of image selection but I am unsure how I would return the image to the form. I know I can start activity for result but I want to visually display the chosen image in the form , either using a path or a thumbnail or something ?

any ideas on the best way to go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best way to go about this would prbably be to use an image chooser and then return the selected image.  An example of this can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550905/access-pictures-from-pictures-app-in-my-android-app)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply , The method in that link works like a charm .All the best