# How to access all pictures on an Android phone?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

Based on this question: [Access pictures from Pictures app in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550905/access-pictures-from-pictures-app-in-my-android-app)

You can access either the internal or external memory for images. But i'm wondering if there's a way to access just a collection of both internal and external, so I don't have to deal with the possibility that some phones have images on an SD card and some have them on internal memory. I'd rather not add another step to my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to write a routine that merged the two separate data structures into one data structure then just use that new data structure that you created.