# Retrieving Images from Mediastore

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve the images from Mediastore.Images.Media I am always getting the cursor to be null. Please suggest how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

```
Uri contenturi = Images.Media.getContentUri("phoneStorage");
    String[] mprojection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String mselection = null;
    String[] mselectionArgs = null;
    String msortOrder ="date_added DESC";
    Cursor mcursor = managedQuery(contenturi, mprojection, mselection, mselectionArgs, msortOrder);
```

When I am checking it says the mcursor to be null, I have tried changing the uri to external storage also tried with no sort order. But still its returning null. Please help

Comment: do u want image from Gallery ?

Comment: Yeah I am looking to import the photos from Gallery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview

Answer (score 0):

buddy try this code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);    
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,getResources().getString(R.string.accept)),1);
```

Now just use `onActivityResult`  method to get image from Gallery.