# Where can I find a full list of parameters that I can put with intent.putExtra to Intent.ACTION_PICK to get video from gallery?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, gallery

I mean, like I define:

```
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
```

to get square image 640x640 from gallery.

In the same way I want to get some video from gallery with certain parameters.

Comment: http://sudhanshuvinodgupta.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-intentactionpick.html

Comment: more help for picking thumbnails :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview