# What are the permission need to live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-permissions

What are the permissions I need in order to set a live wallpaper and get the gallery images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to give two permission

> 1. android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
> 2. android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

Answer (score 0):

For live wallpaper, place the below in your service tag in `manifest.xml`.

`android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER`
`android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper`

And for **Gallery**, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview).

Answer (score 0):

> Which are the permission i given to set live wallpaper and i cant get
>   gallery images

If your questions are interconnected, then permissions have nothing to do with you not being able to *get gallery images*

If these are two independent questions, I would suggest:

1. Start with a good tuturial. For example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html
2. Post the a separate question regarding getting gallery images in your app.

Anyway, to answer the question about permissions alone, depending on how you **configure** your application,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
```

Why I say depending on how you confihure your application is beacuse of this. If you look at the Vogella tutorial linked, the permission `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >` is declared in the `service` in the `application` attribute.

If you look at this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper, it has the permission set to the `application` tag.

Here is (*yet*) another tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android/