# Length of image picked from gallery via intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, gallery

I have a problem. I want to make file uploader app. I'm using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to pick any file from my device. I am receiving the file in onActivityResult like that:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHOOSER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri);
                String fileName = file.getName();
                String filePath = file.getPath();
                int fileSize = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024));

                tvName.setText(fileName);
                tvPath.setText(filePath);
                tvSize.setText(String.valueOf(fileSize) + "kB");
            }
    }
}
```

I want to show user information about picked file. In general everything is fine, but when I choose Image from gallery then:

1. The file name shows no format - it's a number (probably reference to file in memory). When I pick Image via installed file explore I get sth like imagename.png etc, but picked from gallery is like "195493"
2. File.length created from data picked from gallery is 0.

Is there any way to access real image name and size after picking image from Gallery via intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When picking images from the gallery, you don't get a reference to the actual file but to a row in the database. You have to retrieve the actual file path with a Cursor like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474167/642161).

Comment: yes I've just have done it and it works, thanks anyway for response with correct hint

Answer (score 2):

Just input URI from the intent and get the size of any file

```
uri = data.getData();
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.e("TAG", "Name:" + returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.e("TAG","Size: "+Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
```

I think this will help you.