# setImageURI not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the image of my imageButtons when a user is selecting a photo from the gallery or is taking a photo using the camera. The problem is that my imageButtons are just changed to a blank image, but I am getting the file directory. What am I doing wrong? I have created my ImageIntent and onActivityResult from this answer [camera & gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image/12347567#12347567). But here is my onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action
                            .equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
            }

            ImageButton pic1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibPic1);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + selectedImageUri,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pic1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

So i know from the Toast that I am getting the Uri's. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview), and various other solutions which involves some sort of Bitmap, but these are always resulting in app crash and out of memory exceptions.

**Edit**

OnClick method to launch the image intent:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibPic1:
        openImageIntent();
        break;
    }
}
```

Image intent method

```
private void openImageIntent() {

    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Klea" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = Sell.getUniqueImageFilename();
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }
    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
            "Vælg kilde");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Get unique file name method:

```
private static String getUniqueImageFilename() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fileName = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Are both gallery and camera not working? Can you check for both?

Comment: Neither are working. The toast says "file://....." for camera and "content://......" for gallery.

Comment: In camera, u will get exact uri, but in case of gallery, you are getting Content Uri.

Comment: But still none of them are setting the image to other than blank. There is a picture before I insert the new one, and i can set another picture after with a button click, so I don't think there's a mistake in that matter.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. But I can provide an alternate. Convert the image into bitmap and then set bitmap.

Comment: I will definetely have a look at it, if it doesn't have the out of memory errors i have experienced from other solutions. I should maybe clarify that I need up to 4 pictures, and the user is able to remove a picture and take a new one to set in the imagebutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an alternative by creating bitmap from file and setting it. I also include conversion from content uri to actual uri(as to post file, you need actual uri) and image sampling to avoid OOM:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        final boolean isCamera;
        if (data == null) {
            isCamera = true;
        } else {
            final String action = data.getAction();
            if (action == null) {
                isCamera = false;
            } else {
                isCamera = action
                        .equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }

        Uri selectedImageUri;
        if (isCamera) {
            selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
        } else {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            selectedImageUri = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }

        ImageButton pic1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibPic1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + selectedImageUri,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, dpToPx(100),
                dpToPx(100));

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bMapRotate = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        int width = bMapRotate.getWidth();
        int height = bMapRotate.getHeight();
        if (width > height)
            para = height;
        else
            para = width;
        if (bMapRotate != null) {
            pic1.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
        }
    }
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float density = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: It is working, but not when I'm using the camera, this is how i get the: outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory); and i changed  the: else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == -1) {
              filePath= outputFileUri;   to outputFileUri.toString(); Also I don't know if it means anything that i don't have a CAMERA_REQUEST code, since i'm launching the openImageIntent from one intent to chose from camera or other image libraries. Do you want me to post the intent method?

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker Just need to modify a little according to you. Like you used boolean to check whether camera or gallery, I check request code. CAMERA_REQUEST is just a number for camera requestCode.

Comment: yes i know that, but you have both RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE and CAMERA_REQUEST, where i have: startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, int); so I don't know how I can define each number? You can check my questions first link "camera & gallery" to see the code, its the most upvoted answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is throwing a null pointer exception in the bMapRotate.getWidth();  both for camera and gallery.

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker Maybe the bitmap becoming is null. Check if the file path exists or not/

Comment: It does, and it actually works for gallery if I use the setImageURI, but it doesn't work with the camera. I guess I'll have to play around with it for some time.

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker you mean in your original code or in my code?

Comment: it also works with your code now, I just have the problem that when I take pictures with the camera it doesn't save the picture anymore. I don't know what went wrong there, coz it saved them earlier. So naturally it can't load the image from the camera since it's not saved.

Comment: okay I am gonna accept your answer now, since the only bug I have to get rid of now, is that the camera takes +30 sec to create the image in the gallery.

Comment: I have just added the code. Yes it takes extremely long time. After taking the picture i go to the gallery to check if its there since my app says its not, and it isn't. I also have the gallery folder open on my pc. Then after some waiting it suddenly appears in the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63916/discussion-between-berserk-and-kaempe-klunker).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had the same problem as me, as I understood xml properties like `(app:tint="@color/white")` or others in your case in the layout file were hiding my image.

After these lines setImageUri works:

```
binding.image.setImageTintMode(null);
binding.image.setImageURI(uri);
```