# Keep image on image view place

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have one fragment and one activity.. In my layout i have  one image view and one button. I wrote some coding for pick image from galley but i cant place that image on imageView.. I dont Konw how to do. Please any one fix this issue.

My code here:

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

    Button browseProfilePic;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//For option menu

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_profilepic, container,
                false);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        browseProfilePic = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);

        browseProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
               startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PHOTO);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater ) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_pic, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_done:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    }
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview Even if it's not I am sure it can be used to achieve the result.

Comment: Remove onActivityResult from your activity or call super

Comment: @Rohit5k2.. That is activity but i have fragment.

Comment: I Know. But you can get the idea behind it.

Comment: @Appu have you tried removing the `onActivityResult` override from your MainActivity?

Comment: @Appu try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Yeah.. But not working

Comment: @Appu could you post your error?

Comment: I didnt get error...

Comment: If the `Activity` hosting the fragment overrives `onActivityResult` make sure it calls `super.onActivityResult` to give the fragment a chance to handle the result [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/992063), otherwise it assumes the MainActivity.java handled the result.

Comment: @Appu : code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Activity` hosting the fragment overrides `onActivityResult` like your MainActivity does then just make sure it calls `super.onActivityResult` (there's no need to completely remove the override), that should give the fragment a chance to handle the result 
[see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/992063), otherwise it assumes the `MainActivity.java` handled the result and won't call the fragment `onActivityResult`

If even so the image won't show first confirm that the `onActivityResult` is not being called by placing a `Toast` on the beginning of the fragment `onActivityResult` place the result here and we will work from there

Also dont: `getActivity().RESULT_OK` use `Activity.RESULT_OK`

Edit: just tested it out with your code and calling `super.onActivityResult` as expected it works perfect, and won't work without it