# need clarification on answer how to open a specific folder with android intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm writing an android app.

Clicking on a button,

I want the user to choose a photo from a specific (predefined) folder.

I have read few answers to that:

[ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418807/how-can-i-display-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-android-gallery)

but then: how will it work in case of an empty folder?

won't `public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)` open a specific file? which is `allFiles[0]` ?

and i'm not sure what is better for my need? `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` or `Intent.ACTION_PICK`

Comment: What do you mean by "open a folder"?  If you have the path to the folder, why do you need to use an Intent?

Comment: Clicking on a button, 

I want the user to choose a photo from a specific (predefined) folder.

Comment: If you have the path to the folder, the File class will give you a list of the files in the folder.  That list could be presented to the user for his selection.

Comment: but I want the user to choose via native photo Gallery. not via text list I create

Comment: Are you asking: What apps will display images in a given folder, allow a user to select one and return the path to the selected image?  Given the app, what Intent will go to that app passing it the folder?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550905/access-pictures-from-pictures-app-in-my-android-app

Comment: i'm asking how to open a specific folder with Photo Gallery (ie. "screen shots" folder)

Comment: Have you read the doc for the Photo Gallery app?  Does it have notes for developers on how to use it?  Did you read the link I posted earlier?